# How should I stage my bitbucket + heroku django app for development and deployment?

Tags: django, git, heroku, bitbucket, heroku-toolbelt

How should I stage my bitbucket + heroku django app for development and deployment?

I'm working on a Django App.
I don't want to use github because I want to host have a private repo. 
So right now I know how to deploy an app on heroku but how do I do it through bitbucket?

What is this deployment key stuff? 
Do I have to reset my git remote origins or something? 
Do I deploy with different folders? and commit my source code to different folders?

What happens when I want scale up my development environment to multiple computers?
I know I will be using git to monitor changes to the repo, how should I allow all of them to deploy to heroku?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your `git` remote to point to your `bitbucket` URL, then proceed as normal.

Your remote `origin` would be the URL to your bitbucket found in settings. Your remote `heroku` would be pointing to Heroku.

Comment: What do you mean change my git to remote to my bitbucket URL? SSH one or HTTP? Do I have to switch back and forth every time?

Comment: Remove your remote - most likely `origin` then add the remote back via these instructions: https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-remote. The remote that you want to use is the URL in the options section of your `bitbucket`

Comment: I see. So when I would be pushing from the same folder. But have two remote origins. Correct? So I'll be doing a git push heroku master to heroku and git push origin master to bitbucket correct?

Comment: You would have remote `origin` which points to bitbucket, and remote `heroku` which points to heroku. `master` in both instances is the branch that you are pushing/pulling.

Answer (score 0):

@dan-hoerst's answer is still correct but I wanted to draw attention to heroku's new pipeline feature which lets you handle your staging and production environment better way.

> A pipeline is a group of Heroku apps that share the same codebase.
>   Apps in a pipeline are grouped into “review”, “development”,
>   “staging”, and “production” stages representing different deployment
>   steps in a continuous delivery workflow.

You can find more about it here https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/pipelines